# granting database access privileges in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a database currently with the correct permissions. I'm attempting to create a duplicate but i can't get the permissions to be the same.

i created a dump with

`pg_dump database1 > dbdump`

Then i create a database with

`createdb database2`

Then i used the dump to restore the newly created database.

`psql database2 < dbdump`

To see the permissions i did a `\l` and i have the following:

```
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 database1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =T/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | root=CTc/postgres
 database2 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

As you can see, the Access privileges aren't the same on database2.

I tried the following command,

`GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO root;`

but that didn't seem to change anything and i can't log into the database over SSH using the username/password i can with database1.

Answer (score 1):

Check your [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file, that specifies which user on which host can connect to which database using what authentication mechanism.

You might want to base it on the content of the file in the working initial database.